# Generator in quotient group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-spaces

I'm wondering how can we know a quotient group forms a cyclic group.

Suppose we have a quotient  $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle 3\rangle=\{\{1,3\},\{5,7\}\}$ where 
$(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^*=\{1,3,5,7\}$ is a multiplicative group.

This forms a cyclic group since a set of representative composed of each representative for each element is a cyclic group, i.e., $\{1,3\}=\langle 3\rangle$

How can we determine representatives for a quotient group?

Comment: what is $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^*$?

Comment: @Saravanan that's a multiplicative group so I edited the content